# Calling the View of a controller from another controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirect, razor

I am in Booking controller and I need to transfer the user to the Index action of Home controller. I have tried the following solutions:

```
return View("~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml");
```

This will do it in calling the right page, BUT without passing by the controller of that view the page will give null reference errors, as I need to pass something in the ViewBag which is a collection of items.

```
RedirectToAction("Index","HomeController")
```

the problem here is I cannot assign it as a ViewResult: Icannot write:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index","HomeController")
```

because the returned value expected is a ViewResult which does not match the type.
What other solutions I have other than copying the code of the Index action into the other controller?
I don't see this as a replicate because I have explained both the solutions given in other posts are not working.

Comment: Its not clear what your issue is. If you want to redirect to the `Index` method of `HomeController` then its `return RedirectToAction("Index","Home")` (and the method in your `BookingController` can be just `ActionResult`)

Comment: Thanks, renaming ViewResult to ActionResult seems suitable to me. I did not think about it...

Comment: If you want the specific type, then it can be `RedirectResult`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is small mistake in tries. Use `RedirectToAction("Index","Home")`. this should work and solve yours problem.

Comment: Thank you for accepting this as answer but i think you must rename your return type of your controller method 
from ViewResult to ActionResult. By this way only you would be able to redirect to index method of HomeController.